# Unable to post file in Python [Working in Java]

Tags: java, python, post, python-requests, httpurlconnection

I'm quite new to Python and I've been trying to make a post request in Python by sending an xml file along with the request. In Java I could perfectly do it with the below piece of code

```
String url = "https://www.test.com"
URL object = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();

conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader((new FileReader("D:\\test.xml")));
String line1;
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
while ((line1 = br.readLine()) != null) {
    wr.write(line1);
    }

wr.flush();
wr.close();

int HttpResult = conn.getResponseCode();
```

To make it work in Python, I've tried different ways. None of them worked

```
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/xml",
                "Accept": "application/xml",
                }
    url = "https://www.test.com"
    filePath = "D:\\test.xml"
    file_data = [('file', (filePath, open(filePath), 'application/xml'))]
    resp = requests.post(url = url, files=file_data, headers=headers)

    print("resp=",resp.url)
    print("resp=",resp)
```

And few other options as well

```
    files = {'file':(filePath, open(filePath, 'rb'))}
    files = {'file': (filePath, open(filePath, 'rb'), 'application/xml', {'Accept': 'application/xml'})}
```

Even I tried to send the file as data. But to no avail.

```
    data = open("D:\\test.xml", 'rb').read()
    resp = requests.post(url = url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

Please help me to understand where I'm Wrong. I've been breaking my head for hours.
FYI: I'm using Python 3.6.1

Comment: Your last option should work.

Comment: note that it can be useful to look at the request that was sent, this should be available in [`resp.request`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response.request)

Comment: Nope it didn't work. Getting 404. Does that mean the request hit the server and server responded with 404? If it's the case I should ask for server logs to be checked.

Comment: @OlvinRoght It did work. On analyzing the server logs it was identified that there was an issue in the Query Param of the URL. When proper Query Params was supplied it was working.

Comment: @GokuBalu, Great! I'm glad that you fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the official documentation of `requests`, I can find this example (adapted to your case):

```
url = "https://www.test.com"
filePath = "D:\\test.xml"
files = {'file': (filePath, open(filePath, 'rb'), 'application/vnd.ms-excel', {'Expires': '0'})}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

The original quickstart example is here:
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file